# how to create a pop-up that displays a generic information

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table that contains the fields below and I created a model using EF:

```
Event Details

EventMngID
Event_name
Event_location
Event_Date
EM_opt1Question1
EM_opt1Answer1
EM_opt1Question2
EM_opt1Answer2
EM_opt1Question3
EM_opt1Answer3
EM_opt1Question4
EM_opt1Answer4
```

I have a page that display the event Information and custom question they are in seperate division. As you can see, the second image has a Edit Choices action link. When I click the edit it will display a pop-up that displays the answers. From the pop-up I can modify the values and save the answer. All changes should reflects in the Answer Field dropdownlist of the Custom Question division. My problem here is, what is the mechanism to use, since the table contains 4 answer field
if will I going to do like this in the pop-up (below code) then what about the Answer2 ..4? And I am sure it will raised an error. Any help please on how to solved this problem or if there is a link that is related to my problem please send it to me.

```
     <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Answer1) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer1) %>
    </div>
```

[image: Event Details Information]

[image: Custom Question]

[image]

Comment: Why not use Jquery UI and more specifically, the Dialog? http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: I am using jquery dialog  for the pop-up

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking how to store multiple answers per question?  Or are you asking about some sort of validation on the answers?

Comment: Well, I am asking on how to display the answer in the pop-up window. For eg, If my field is opt1Answer1 it will display the opt1Answer1 values, if my field is opt1Answer2 then it will display the opt1Answer2 values and so on

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have two options.

The first (which I do not think is the best option) is to figure out which question and answer number is being edited and generate your query dynamically.  I'm not sure if you are using some ORM like Entity Framework but if you are, you will then need to have some long if/elseif statement like the following:

```
if (editing question 1)
     return (query to get question and answer 1)
else if (editing question 2)
     return (query to get question and answer 2)
```

On the other hand, if you are just writing the sql queries dynamically and using ADO.NET, you can generate the query text a bit easier.  Again, I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS SOLUTION.

The better solution would be to normalize your database and separate the questions and answers into their own table and not lump them into the EventDetails table.  You would need to remove each EM_opt1QuestionX and EM_opt1AnswerX columns from the table and create a new table with some structure like the following:

```
QuestionAnswer
--------
QuestionAnswerID
EventMngID
Question
Answer
```

Then each question and answer has their own id which allows you to easily target a given record.  This also allows you to have as many or as few questions and answers as you need without having to try and guess the maximum number of questions that would be needed.

Comment: Actually that is also my idea, but the client designed it and they didn't allow to modify the structure of the table